# When precompiling ASP.NET MVC 4 project in Visual Studio 2012, does it try to resolve the entire config chain locally?

Tags: web-config, visual-studio-2012, precompile, web-config-transform, one-click-web-publishing

Can someone please confirm or deny my assumption below and/or offer any alternatives?

### My Goal

I'd like to be able to precompile and merge my ASP.NET MVC 4 application (as documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410108.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh475319.aspx)) when one-click publishing to our production environment.

### The Symptom

I've got an ASP.NET MVC 4 project in Visual Studio 2012. My `Web.config` contains various entries that are removed in the `Web.Release.config` transformation. One of the removed entries is the entire `configSections` element because we maintain those entries in the production server's `Machine.config`.

However, when I configure my project to precompile and merge for release publication, I get the following error:

```
Unrecognized configuration section [our custom section name]
```

### My Assumption

What I assume is happening is that it is precompiling everything locally before publishing to the production server (which makes perfect sense) but that part of that precompilation process is to resolve and validate the entire `.config` chain, from the project's `Web.config` up to my local `Machine.config` (which doesn't make much sense, practically). And since my local `Machine.config` does not declare `configSections` (or any of the other settings we rely on the production server's `Machine.config` for), the resolved `Web.config` doesn't validate.

And since the `Web.config` doesn't validate, the site can't be precompiled and so nothing is ever published to production.

### The Rub

If that is indeed what's happening, then we won't be able to precompile, because the only solution I can think of (other than some potential configuration option I haven't been able to find) would be for all of our developers to have local copies of our production server's `Machine.config` on their machines. And that simply isn't reasonable because it defeats the whole purpose of having those common settings declared in a single location.